# recode a python function for use in php

Tags: php, python, sockets

in python i find it relatively easy to connect to connect to a socket with a given host and port and get the received data. take the following code for example (fragment):

```
connected = False

 def ping(self, pingid):
  time.sleep(60)
  while connected and pingid == 1111:
    self.sock.send(b'/r/n/x00')
    time.sleep(60)


def connect(host):
    sock = socket.socket() 
    sock.connect((host, whateverport))
    self.sock = sock
    connected = True
    _thread.start_new_thread(ping, (1111,))
    b = b""        
    while not b.endswith(b"\x00"): 
        print(sock.recv(1024))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect(whateverhost)
```

using this i am able to connect to a given host and keep a connection. i tried re-coding this in php but for the life of me i could not get it to work is there (if possible) a way to re-code this efficiently in php? the reason why i am doing this is because i can run this locally, however most free hosts do not support python.

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: long lost after a friend let me user their python compatible server. but unfortunately they cancelled the subscription and i am in need of a php method again.

Comment: Most _free_ hosts would not like/allow you grabbing and keeping hold of one or more of *their* ports.

Comment: Well...the Python tag should be removed imo since this question has nothing to do with Python really. Also I don't really think it's that hard to find examples of Perl connecting to a host and doing some simple pings on google. :p

Comment: ah but php is the desired language. this is only a fragment of a library that i made in python. i want to spread out in to php but i have issues with the sockets

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant PHP. I'm just sleepy.